# Cloud Firestore trigger not working for Cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to invoke a Cloud Function using the Cloud Firestore trigger. Basically, my cloud function is taking a full export of my sub collection 'reviews' whenever a new document is added to 'reviews'. I have around 6-7 documents inside my 'reviews' sub collection. I deployed the function through the console and the deployment completed. However, this function is not getting triggered whenever I add a new document to my 'reviews' sub collection. Can someone please tell me what could be the issue?

**Trigger type:** Cloud Firestore (Beta)
**Event type:** providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write
**Document Path:** test_restaurant/{reviews}

[image]

**EDIT:**
I want my cloud function to only export the new documents added to my firestore to my GCP bucket. Below is the function I am trying to write:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://ABC/trigger_test'
exports.newFirestoreBackup = functions.firestore
  .document('test_restaurant/{Id}/reviews/{Id}') 
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
   const databaseName = client.databasePath(
   // process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
   "FS-123",
    '(default)'
  );
return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: ['reviews'],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  
  
  });
```

**CONSOLE SNIPPET:**
[image]

Comment: Can you pls share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: Edited the question with my cloud function code @Renaud Tarnec

Answer (score 1):

You don't share any code, but if you want your Cloud Function to be triggered "whenever [you] add a new document to the `reviews` subcollection", it should be declared with the following path:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('test_restaurant/{restaurantId}/reviews/{reviewId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {...});
```

---

You could use an [`onWrite()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=1#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document) trigger as well, with the same path.

Comment: Do I have to include the above code in my index.js even if i am creating the cloud function through console? I am already specifying my trigger and the document path in console itself, so do i need to again mention this bit inside my cloud function? (I have attached the console snippet too)